# Congruence module algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is:  Find all integers x,y s.t.   $x^2+y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod5$

My own attempt is below, but I don't think it is correct.

$5|x^2+y^2 \implies x^2+y^2=5t ,\: t \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Hence $x= \sqrt{5t-y^2}$

```
enter preformatted text here
```

Comment: Use $1^2+2^2=5$ and $0+0=0$.

Comment: I mean, yes, if $x^2+y^2=5t$ then $x=\sqrt{5t-y^2}$, but that doesn't seem relevant at all. Whether or not $x^2+y^2$ is divisible by $5$ depends only on the residues of $x$ and $y$ mod $5$, so you just have to check cases.

Answer (score 1):

use that if $$x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4\mod 5$$ then $$x^2\equiv 0,1,4\mod 5$$

Comment: It would simpler writing the elements $0,\pm1,\pm2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i^2 + y_i^2 = r_i$. Then $(x_1 x_2 - y_1y_2)^2 + (x_1y_2 + x_2y_1)^2 = r_1r_2 $. If we let $r_1 = 5$, then $x_1 = 1$ and $y_1 = 2$. If $x$, $y$ are any integers, then $(x - 2y)^2 + (2x + x)^2 = (x^2 + y^2)5$.

The next step is to reverse the above and conclude the converse, that any $x $, $y$ as in the problem can be obtained in this way.